# Web3 1.0.0 import fails with Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in web3-bzz

Tags: web3js, swarm

I'm trying to use web3@1.0.0-beta11 on MacOs Sierra 10.12.5 
Build works when I import only the web3-eth and web3-utils.
When I import the whole web3 package then build fails with errors about swarm-js.

```
var Web3 = require('web3');
```

Output from `npm run build` :

```
WARNING in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mimetype/mimetype.js
18:5-12 Critical dependency: require function is used in a way in which dependencies cannot be statically extracted

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'child_process' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js 373:19-48
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js 9:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'got' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js 11:10-24
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js 5:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mz/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mz'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mz/fs.js 7:7-20
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-promise/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mkdirp'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mkdirp/index.js 2:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mkdirp-promise/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js 1:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mz/fs.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-promise/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/proxy-writer.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/proxy-writer.js 14:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/empty/index.js 3:11-24
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-promise/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs/fs.js 3:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/graceful-fs/graceful-fs.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/mz/fs.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-promise/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js 6:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/jsonfile'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/jsonfile/index.js 5:8-21
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/jsonfile.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/json/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-extra/lib/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs-promise/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/glob.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/glob.js 43:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/sync.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/sync.js 4:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js 8:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx

ERROR in ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js
Module not found: Error: Can't resolve 'fs' in '/Users/petro/ether/ucd-poc/node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath'
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath/old.js 24:9-22
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fs.realpath/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/glob/glob.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/rimraf/rimraf.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/lib/writer.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/fstream/fstream.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/tar.gz/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/files.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/node_modules/swarm-js/lib/swarm.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/packages/web3-bzz/src/index.js
 @ ./node_modules/web3/src/index.js
 @ ./app/javascripts/app.jsx
```

Comment: this is on windows maybe? Check solutions with the 'fs' is a current fail error.

Comment: MacOS Sierra 10.12.5

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It works now with web3@1.0.0-beta13.

I assume the new beta version solved the issue but I also had two web3 npm installs: a local & global one. The global was 0.19.1 which I uninstalled.